# Radio button multidimensional array

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, radio-button

I am working with radio buttons.

```
<input type="radio" value="1" name="report[1][AP]">
<input type="radio" value="2" name="report[1][AP]">

<input type="radio" value="1" name="report[1][DCI]">
<input type="radio" value="2" name="report[1][DCI]">

<input type="radio" value="1" name="report[2][AP]">
<input type="radio" value="2" name="report[2][AP]">

<input type="radio" value="1" name="report[2][DCI]">
<input type="radio" value="2" name="report[2][DCI]">
```

If report[1][AP] is checked then report[1][DCI] also should be checked, OR If report[1][DCI] is checked then report[1][AP] also should be checked.

Similarly;

if report[2][AP] is checked then report[2][DCI] also should be checked, OR if report[2][DCI] is checked then report[2][AP] also should be checked.

What should I do?

I am using this:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('click', function(){
    var found = $(this).attr('name');
    var founds = found.substring(0, found.indexOf(']'))+"]";
    $("input[type="+founds+"]").prop('required',true);
});
```

Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[type=report_time[1]]

Comment: "also should be checked"... means should be "Required". must be checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here I implemented in Angular 7 Radio button multidimensional array**

*The Idea behind this is that with radio button we have name property which makes single select either by row or column but for both row and column. I placed the row in name and handled column with javascript whenever button will click.*

> This is HTML CODE

```
<section class="editor">
 <strong>Editor</strong>
  <div>
   <label>Add option</label>
   <button (click)="addOption()">+</button>
  <div *ngFor="let option of options;let i = index">
  <span>{{option.title +(i+1)}}</span><button (click)="deleteOption(i)" 
    *ngIf="options.length>2">X</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
<hr>
<section>
 <strong>Builder</strong>
  <div class="builder">
    <label>Question title goes here</label><br>
    <div *ngFor="let option of options;let row_index = index">
     <span>{{option.title +(row_index+1)}}</span>
     <span *ngFor="let rank of options;let column_index=index">
       <input type="radio" name="{{row_index}}" class="{{column_index}}" 
         (click)="check(column_index,$event)">
     </span>
   </div>   
  </div>
</section>
```

> And this is my .ts file code where I Implemented with Javascript

```
export class AppComponent {
  options = [{
  title: "option",
  rank: 0,
}, {
 title: "option",
 rank: 0
}]
constructor() {

 }
  ngOnInit(): void { }
 addOption() {
  this.options.push({
  title: "option",
  rank: 0
  })
 }
deleteOption(i) {
  this.options.splice(i, 1);
}
check(column_index, event) {

Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(column_index)).map(x=>x['checked']=false);
event.target.checked=true;
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this..

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('click', function(){
    var namePattern = /([a-z]*)(\[[0-9]\])(\[[A-Z]*\])/i;
    var found = $(this).attr('name').match(namePattern);

    var required = '[AP]';
    if(found[3] === '[AP]') {
        required = '[DCI]';
    }

    var reqButtonName = found[1] + found[2] + required;
    var reqButtonWithValue1 = $('[name="' + reqButtonName + '"]')[0];
 // $(reqButtonWithValue1).prop('checked', 'checked');
    $(reqButtonWithValue1).prop('required', 'required');
});
```

This will check the radio button [DCI]/[AP] with `value=1`

Comment: should not checked automatically... I want to make other radio buttons required.

Comment: you just need another function that can handle [DCI] click event.

Comment: I have unified both the click handlers... I am not sure about what you mean by making other radio buttons required

Comment: required means "do not submit form".

Comment: oh.. then that makes it more simple.. just capture the form submit and check the desired elements are checked.. I need your full html if you want me to me to give you the code..

Comment: okay.. Try my updated function.. this should do what you are looking for